# Configure subdomain to point to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a domain www.test.com which points to a website which was created using WIX. Hence, the nameserver in my www.test.com (GoDaddy is the registrar, so I can edit my nameserver at https://dcc.godaddy.com) domain points to

```
ns7.wixdns.net
ns8.wixdns.net
```

Now I want to have admin.test.com to point to my S3 bucket `http://admin.test.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Login`

I have set my S3 bucket Properties > Static Website Hosting > Redirect Requests to `admin.test.com` and add alias record in Route 53 as suggested by [this Amazon Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-add-arecord-to-hostedzone)

Now I'm pretty sure I need to point my domain's nameserver to this Route 53, but I'm confused what and/or where I should do it. If I change the nameserver in https://dcc.godaddy.com to something else, pretty sure my wix hosted website will be inaccessible.

Comment: Sounds like WIX are managing DNS for your domain name, so you'd probably need to add an A record for `admin.test.com`within the WIX [control panel](https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-or-updating-a-records-in-your-wix-account) rather than GoDaddy.

Comment: We can do that in WIX is it? I'm going to ask my colleague for the WIX login then.

Comment: Should be able to.  You'd need to find what to point the A record (or from reading more likely a CNAME) to.  The accepted answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/551431/aws-s3-static-hosting-with-custom-domain-routing-bare-domain?rq=1) seems similar.

Comment: Using the A record form in Wix, I can put the hostname `admin.test.com` but the field `points to` only allow IP address. So what I did was I use the CNAME form instead. I put the hostname as `admin.test.com`  and points to `http://admin.test.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/` . I can access my website from http://admin.test.com/login now , but it seems every now and then I will get `This site can't be reached error`. Is it because the dns is not fully propagated yet?  I'll give a more proper try in a few hours then.